# How to Include a signed value in an 8086 assembly program?

Tags: assembly, signed, emu8086

I didn't understand the concept of including signed value when writing it, for example writing a code that includes a signed value (for example -12) then returns it its absolute value (12)?

Comment: What do you mean by "including a signed value"? I've never heard that before.

Comment: @MargaretBloom it is in assembly language 8086, signed arithmetic operation. for different value of D0 and D1. write a program which receives a signed value in D0 and which returns its absolute value in D1

Comment: Think of an algorithm that makes the absolute value from any (positive/negative) number

Comment: @bill7 You may want to clear your terminology then. Again, "to include a signed value" doesn't ring any bell for me. I may be the only one but this operation goes under the name of "taking the absolute value" This will improve your chance of getting an answer (eventually through a duplicate, since this is surely not the first time somebody asks about absolute values)..

Comment: @MargaretBloom , include a signed value in an 8086 program. for example the value of -1 cannot be written directly in the code so it must be translated into signed value mode. this is what I wanted to do it then execute it in absolute value

Comment: Negative numbers can be written in most assemblers. Anyway, read about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: If `add dx, -5` doesn't work, use a better assembler (for example NASM).  You don't need to manually encode the 2's complement bit-pattern, that's part of the point of having an assembler instead of writing raw machine code.

Comment: What exact asm source did you try to write using a negative number, and what actually happened to make you think it didn't work?  If you provide a [mcve], we can probably tell you what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If by *including signed value when writing it* you mean reading a signed numeric value at run-time from the user who types it at their keyboard, then the program has to parse the value,  remember if it begun with **-** sign, then parse the following digits as usual, and if sign **-** was remembered, NEGate the final value.
Or, if absolute (nonnegative) value is requested, then the sign should be ignored.

If by *including signed value when writing it* you mean reading a signed numeric value at assembly-time from the source file, for instance with instruction like `MOV AX,-12`, then assembler takes care of correct parsing the number -12. If absolute value of immediate is requested, it's possible to invert it with `NEG AX` if `TEST AX,AX` sets the SignFlag. But every sane programmer would convert the number to absolute value in his/her head instead of doing it by CPU at run-time, of course.

Answer (score 1):

In a language like C, signed vs. unsigned is a property of a data type.  Data types are used to declare variables, and variables are used to hold values.  Thus, we combine size and sign'ness together into one concept of data type that is captured in one place for a given variable, namely at its declaration.

In assembly language, these concerns are spread out.  For one, we don't really have variables, we have storage, whether memory or registers.  To see the difference, in assembly language we can (and do often) change the meaning of storage — reuse the same storage for another logical purpose (a different variable in C).  This applies in particular to the registers, but also can happen with memory (especially on the stack).

To reserve memory (as in global storage), we can declare a number of bytes of storage, yet without consideration of sign.  Depending on the assembler we can use signed or unsigned decimal values to initialize the storage, but it is still just initialized storage and not on the same level as an initialized variable with a proper data type in C.

During usage of that memory, access to read or write that storage, is when we choose to interpret as signed or unsigned.  Consistency is programmer responsibility: every time that logical variable is accessed as storage, we must use instructions that either don't care about sign, or use the proper sign/unsigned instructions.  When we copy a value from one location to another we usually don't care about sign'ness (size is important).  When we add or subtract, these arithmetic operations work on both signed and unsigned types.  When we compare items (or check for overflow of addition/subtraction) we need to be very aware of signed vs. unsigned data.

In C, we can use casts to reinterpret variables with differing sign, but we cannot redeclare or repurpose a variable to have different sign'ness.  The language ensures that whenever we reference a variable it refers to the same data type.  In assembly it is up to the individual instructions to refer to the storage for a variable in the same consistent way for the intended sign'ness of the variables.

Comment: Granted that the question is unclear and too broad (it's a "do my homework for me" question) and granted that you may have written this answer before the OP clarified their terminology in the comments, I still don't see how this properly answers the question. It doesn't deserve a downvote because all you wrote is correct, well exposed and informative but it doesn't address how to implement an absolute value function in 8086 assembly (if I understood the OP's question right).

Comment: @Margaret Bloom it does not exist, we cannot execute in absolute value on a program 8086 ?